# How to get around myspace's msplinks

Tags: html, forms, myspace

Im editing the html of a myspace page to insert a form. For the 'action' attribute of the form I have a web address (naturally). It works fine on a real website, but what happens with myspace is that any links you enter are routed through the server (I believe) are replaced with an msplinks link instead. This royally effs up my form and I'm not sure how to get around it.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I know this is in flash but here http://www.myspace.com/brokensocialscene if you click on free download you get a box where you can enter your email.

Comment: Pretty sure myspace doesn't allow you to hijack their pages.

Comment: so there is no way you can think of that I can just enter in an email box for someone to subscribe to an email list?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a little late. But here is what I did:

1. Go to tinyurl.com or another website which shortens urls.
2. Shorten the url and
3. use the new short url in stead of the original (long url) for myspace and you'll see, it works!

Well actually it is not a workaround for msplinks, but the result is the same, since you can now direct to any url.

Actually what you're doing is the same thing myspace did. Making the url redirect. You can use this for any kind of url you like. Skype Urls, itunes urls etc..

I used it for the url to launch iTunes and subscribe to my podcast. As you can see in the link below, it even allows url's other then http://

original url:    itpc://dl.dropbox.com/u/14194526/itunes_podcast_feed.rng

the short url I used is: http://tinyurl.com/2uh3m23

Hope you can still use it.